# SVG overlapping shapes with Recharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg, recharts

I am using Recharts to create a simple pie chart.
My issue likely stems from the fact the entire thing is SVG-based.
I would like to have a selected pie slice change color (both fill and stroke).
So I do the following:

```js
import { useState } from 'react';
import { Sector, Pie, PieChart, ResponsiveContainer } from 'recharts';

export function SinglePie({ data }) {
    const [selectedCellLabel, setHighlightedCell] = useState(undefined);

    const onMouseEnter = (event) => setHighlightedCell(event.payload.payload.label);
    const onMouseLeave = () => setHighlightedCell(undefined);

    function renderActiveShape(props) {
        return <Sector {...props} fill="#CFBCF7" stroke="#7C53E4" />;
    }

    return (
        <ResponsiveContainer width="100%" height="100%">
            <PieChart>
                <Pie
                    data={data}
                    activeIndex={data.findIndex((datum) => datum.label === selectedCellLabel)}
                    activeShape={renderActiveShape}
                    dataKey={ChartDataKeys.VALUE}
                    nameKey={ChartDataKeys.LABEL}
                    fill="#CEF1EE"
                    stroke="#64E0D5"
                    onMouseEnter={onMouseEnter}
                    onMouseLeave={onMouseLeave}
                />
            </PieChart>
        </ResponsiveContainer>
    );
}
```

Then render with:

```
<div style={{ width: 250, height: 250 }}>
    <SinglePie data={[
        {
            label: 'First Slice',
            value: 4,
        },
        {
            label: 'Second Slice',
            value: 6,
        },
        {
            label: 'Third Slice',
            value: 2,
        },
    ]} />
</div>
```

And unfortunately, on hovering the First Slice, what I see is this:

[image]

However, hovering the Third Slice looks ok:

[image]

You can see the difference between stroke width in the two cases. this is because the SVG slices overlap each other.
I know that SVG rendering is based on order, and adding a `z` prop won't help. But what will?

I would like to be able to see all slices with their strokes, as is required by my UI designer:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.raise()` function of [d3 library](https://d3js.org/).

First, you need to add `<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>` tag to your `index.html`.

And then you can move the selected slice to last in your `onMouseEnter` function like this:

```
const onMouseEnter = (event) => {
    setHighlightedCell(event.payload.payload.label);
    const selectedIndex = data.findIndex(
      (datum) => datum.label === event.payload.payload.label
    );
    if (selectedIndex > -1) {
      const gListItem = d3.select(
        `.recharts-pie-sector:has(path[name="${event.payload.payload.label}"])`
      );
      gListItem.raise();
    }
};
```

You can take a look at [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bfhsba?file=src%2FSinglePie.js,src%2FApp.js,public%2Findex.html) for a live working example of this solution.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me with other charts as well.